# As above, so below

Tags: quotes

I unable to fathom the quote of Hermes Trismegistus which is given Below;

1)As above, so below,

2) as within, so without,

3)as the universe, so the soul

Kindly also suggest, if possible, how we can use this quotes in our colloquial.
Reference link
http://treeofknowledgecoven.com/2012/07/01/as-above-so-below-as-within-so-without-as-the-universe-so-the-soul/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine omitted "it is" or "is" in each example. This is the sense of them:  As IT IS above, so IT IS below. As IT IS within, so IT IS without (meaning outside of).  As the universe IS, so IS the soul.

Comment: Thanks for point out grammatical error but how we can use them in our colloquial?

Comment: This was not a grammatical error; it is common to leave out certain words.  As to the application of these maxims, the first means that human life on earth is (or should) be like the supposed behavior of god(s) in heaven. The second means that internal workings of the body or mind are mirrored in the outside world (this is a bit of a stretch). The third is a bit of a puzzler—how is the universe like the soul?  The universe is infinite; other than that I find it hard to make a parallel.